# Boostrap 3 Affix Sidebar not working right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://tutsme-webdesign.info/bootstrap-3-affix/) to create an affix for my site, but there are a few things that are off and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

1. When scrolling, the width of the ul changes slightly, from 165-166px
2. After scrolling down, the affix doesn't stay at the top but remains fixed near the bottom of the page
3. The research li sometimes doesn't get highlighted at all

Here's my code: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/joziyoke/1/edit)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the bootstrap docs:

The affix plugin toggles between three classes, each representing a particular state: `.affix`, `.affix-top`, and `.affix-bottom`. You **must** provide the styles for these classes yourself (independent of this plugin) to handle the actual positions.

That should fix your issues with 1 and 2. With issue number 3, if you scroll too fast it will skip it because it is so close to the next anchor when compared with the height of the page. You could increase the spacing or add more content.

Comment: The docs seem pretty vague to me. It says I must provide CSS positioning for .affix, .affix-top and .affix-bottom, but also says that for .affix-top, no CSS positioning is required, for .affix, Bootstrap's code CSS already sets ``position: fixed``, and that for .affix-bottom, we should add ``position: absolute`` when necessary. But when exactly is it necessary?

Comment: Also, it introduces ``data-offset-top`` and ``data-offset-bottom``, but doesn't clearly say how to select the values for these attributes...

Comment: I have encountered the exact same problems with the affix plugin and I agree it is quite vague. Your best bet is to experiment or have a look around at some other bootstrap sites that are utilizing the plugin.